# About reflexivity of ultrapower

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ultrapowers

It is obvious that for a Banach space $E$, $E$ is reflexive iff $\ell^2(E)$ is reflexive. Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter. Is the reflexivity of $(E)_\mathcal U$ equivalent to refelxivity of $(\ell^2(E))_\mathcal U$?

Comment: Yes: $(E)_{\mathcal{U}}$ is reflexive if and only if $E$ is super reflexive if and only if $E$ is uniformly convex for an equivalent norm if and only if $\ell^2(E)$ is uniformly convex for an equivalent norm if and only if $\ell^2(E)$ is super reflexive if and only if $(\ell^2(E))_{\mathcal{U}}$ is reflexive.

Comment: @JochenGlueck  Is it enough for a Banach space $E$ to be superreflexive, if $(E)_\mathcal U$ is reflexive only for one ultrafilter?!!! I think we have $E$ is superreflexive if and only if $(E)_\mathcal U$  is reflexive for all ultrafilter $\mathcal U$.

Comment: A single countably incomplete ultrafilter is enough.

Comment: Oh, you're right; it didn't take into account that $\mathcal{U}$ is fixed. But see @Mathew Daws' comment.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Can you please let me know where I can find the proof of your claim?

Comment: See Theorem 6.3 in Heinrich's paper, using that reflexivity is separably determined.

Comment: @MatthewDaws As you mentioned in your thesis, I think a Banach space $E$ is superreflexive iff $(E)_\mathcal U$ is reflexive for all countably incomplete ultrafilter $\mathcal U$, not only for one ultrafilter!

Comment: I'm not sure why you believe that a graduate student (myself some years ago) should be trusted to have stated a theorem in maximum generality...

Comment: @MatthewDaws You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$The confusion seems to be over the following claim:

> **Claim:** Let $\mc U$ be a countably incomplete ultrafilter, and let $E$ be a Banach space.  If $(E)_{\mc U}$ is reflexive, then $E$ is super-reflexive.

To start with, we use the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem to observe that a Banach space $F$ is reflexive if and only if every *separable* subspace of $F$ is reflexive.  [Question: Do we need Eberlein-Smulian to show this?]

Recall also that $\mc U$ being *countably incomplete* means that there is a nested sequence of sets $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ in $\mc U$ with $\cap_i A_i = \emptyset$.  I think of this property as allowing us to embed sequential convergence into convergence along $\mc U$.

Finally, let us recall Theorem 6.3 in Heinrich's paper:

> If $F$ is a separable Banach space finitely representable in $E$ then $F$ embeds isometrically into $(E)_{\mc U}$ for any countably incomplete $\mc U$.

Suppose towards a contradiction that $E$ is not super-reflexive, so there is a non-reflexive $F$ finitely representable in $E$.  There is hence a separable subspace $F_0$ of $F$ which is not reflexive.  Clearly $F_0$ is still finitely representably in $E$, and so isometric to a subspace of $(E)_{\mc U}$.  Hence $(E)_{\mc U}$ is not reflexive, contrary to assumption.

We then proceed exactly as Jochen Glueck's comment.

**Edit:** As Tomek points out, if $E$ is separable (with no other condition) and $\mc U$ is countably *complete*, then $(E)_{\mc U} = E$ canonically.  Here's a proof (which I hadn't realised before).  That $\mc U$ is countably complete is equivalent to the property that if $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $\mc U$ then also $\cap_n A_n \in \mc U$.  Let $\mc U$ be on a set $I$, and let $A_n\subseteq I$ be any sequence of subsets which cover $I$, so $\cup_n A_n = I$.  We claim that then some $A_n\in\mc U$.  For if not, $I\setminus A_n\in\mc U$ for all $n$ (as $\mc U$ is an ultrafilter) and so $\cap_n (I\setminus A_n) = \emptyset\in\mc U$, contradiction.

Let $(x_n)$ be a dense sequence in $E$, and let $(y_i)\in (E)_{\mc U}$.  Consider the sets
$$ A_{n,m} = \{ i : \|y_i - x_n\| < 1/m \}. $$
As $(x_n)$ is dense, for any fixed $i$ and $m$ there is some $n$ with $\|y_i-x_n\|<1/m$.  So $(A_{n,m})$ covers $I$, and so there is some $A_{n,m}\in\mc U$.  Fix this $n$ and consider $A_{n,k}\subseteq A_{n,m}$ for $k\geq m$.  Repeating the argument finds that there is an increasing sequence $m \leq k_1 < k_2 < k_3 < \cdots$ with $A_{n,k_i}\in\mc U$ for each $i$.  Hence
$$ \bigcap_i A_{n,k_i} = \{ i : y_i=x_n \} \in\mc U $$
and so $(y_i) = x_n\in E$ in $(E)_{\mc U}$.

Comment: How do we answer the above question when $\mathcal U$ is not countably incomplete?

Comment: That I am not sure about.  If $\mc U$ is not countably incomplete, then you are sort of into the realm of set theory, and not analysis any more...

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan, if $E$ is separable and $\mathcal U$ happens to be countably complete, then $E\cong E^{\mathcal U}$, so you cannot counclude anything.

Comment: @TomekKania In the mentioned situation, we have also $(\ell^2(E))_\mathcal U\cong\ell^2(E)$, so the reflexivity of spaces are equivalent.

Comment: @MatthewDaws It is true that if $(A_n)$ is a sequence of subsets of $I$ such that $\bigcup A_n\in\mathcal U$ then at least one of $A_n$'s is in $\mathcal U$

Comment: In the case of countably complete ultrafilter, then yes.  The same argument I gave for the case when $\cup A_n = I$.

Comment: @MatthewDaws, you mean `$E$ is separable' not merely reflexive (this is a typo as you employ separability, of course).